# Find the position of an integer A in integer B for multiple occurence

Tags: java, indexof

I am trying to find the position of `integer A` in `integer B`.

`Example:`

```
A = 5;
B = 45356;
```

I am using `indexOf()` but after all the position has been searched the output has -1 in it, how can I remove this?

`Output for the above:`

```
1
3
-1
```

Comment: Don't print it if it's -1?

Comment: It appears you are seeking help in debugging your code. If that is the case, then don't you think you should post your code?